# $\lim _{x\to 4}\frac{\sqrt{5-x}-1}{2-\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Find the limit of $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{5-x}-1}{2-\sqrt{x}}$ when x approaches 4.

I have no idea where to start with this problem.

Comment: Have you studied L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: No I haven't studied that rule.

Comment: You can read about L'Hospital's Rule here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html

Comment: This looks like typical "multiply by one" case. Try to multiply it by $\frac{2+\sqrt{x}}{2+\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: It will give out $\lim_{x \to 4}(2- \sqrt{x})(2+ \sqrt{x}) = \lim_{x \to 4}(2^2- x) = 0$

Answer (score 3):

**Without using L'Hospital's rule**

Notice,

Rationalizing the numerator & denominator as follows
$$\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{\sqrt{5-x}-1}{2-\sqrt{x}}$$ 
$$=\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{(\sqrt{5-x}-1)(\sqrt{5-x}+1)(2+\sqrt{x})}{(2-\sqrt{x})(2+\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{5-x}+1)}$$ 
$$=\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{(5-x-1)(2+\sqrt{x})}{(4-x)(\sqrt{5-x}+1)}$$ 
$$=\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{(4-x)(2+\sqrt{x})}{(4-x)(\sqrt{5-x}+1)}$$ 
$$=\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{2+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{5-x}+1}$$ 
$$=\frac{2+\sqrt{4}}{\sqrt{5-4}+1}=\frac{4}{2}=\color{blue}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice,

Using l'Hopital's rule for $\frac{0}{0}$ form
$$\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{\sqrt{5-x}-1}{2-\sqrt{x}}$$ 
$$=\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{5-x}-1)}{\frac{d}{dx}(2-\sqrt{x})}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{5-x}}}{\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{x}}}$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 4}\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{5-x}}$$ $$=\frac{\sqrt{4}}{\sqrt{5-4}}=\frac{2}{1}=\color{red}{2}$$